# Showing $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\|a+h\| - \bigg(\|a\| + \frac{a\cdot h}{\|a\|}\bigg)}{\|h\|} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Show for any $a \neq 0 $ we have:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\|a+h\| - \bigg(\|a\| + \frac{a\cdot h}{\|a\|}\bigg)}{\|h\|} = 0$$

Note: all terms are vectors of any dimension.

Hint: remember that $x - y = \frac{x^{2} - y ^{2}}{x+y}$

**Attempt**:

I've gotten this far

$$\frac{\|a+h\|^{2} - \bigg(\|a\| + \frac{a\cdot h}{\|a\|}\bigg)^{2}}{\|h\| \bigg(\|a+h\| + \bigg(\|a\| + \frac{a\cdot h}{\|a\|}\bigg)\bigg)}$$

I expanded it form here, but I don't see anything that remotely looks like it will help in cancelling out the $\|h\|$ term.

I do have Cauchy Schwartz available, but it won't make any inequality true if I apply it to $a \cdot h$

Comment: I see the motivation for this proof as well : Isn't this the calculation behind finding the derivative of the norm function at a non-zero point? (It's well known that it isn't differentiable at zero).

Comment: Well the norm is defined in the next chapter I'm doing after this question so technically, I don't "know" of it yet....so I was trying to figure this out based on first principles only.

Comment: Fair enough, it was to be derived using first principles : I'm happy with your question, but if posters know the additional information that such a calculation is useful for a deeper reason, they will be happy to read through it, so your question will receive better attention. I just pointed this out so that I could also look for a duplicate, but the point is that no one uses the $\|\cdot\|$ as is, and instead prefer to use the Euclidean formula, which I didn't think reflected well on what was being done here.

Comment: I appreciate it actually because when doing the exercise one of the questions I ask myself is "What is this result intending to show me?" and here you are expounding on it. Thanks

Comment: That attitude of exploring why a certain question was asked will take you very far in mathematics! I wish you a good journey ahead, and I'll push you ahead with a +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. Expanding the numerator of the last expression gives
$$
\|a+h\|^{2} - \bigg(\|a\| + \frac{a\cdot h}{\|a\|}\bigg)^{2}
= \|a\|^2 + 2a \cdot h  + \|h\|^2 - \|a\|^2 - 2 a \cdot h-\frac{(a \cdot h)^2}{\|a\|^2} \\
=  \|h\|^2-\frac{(a \cdot h)^2}{\|a\|^2}
$$
and using the triangle inequality and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality one sees that the absolute value is
$$
\le \|h\|^2 + \frac{(\|a\| \|h\|)^2}{\|a\|^2} = 2 \|h\|^2
$$.

Therefore
$$
 \frac{\left|\|a+h\| - \bigg(\|a\| + \frac{a\cdot h}{\|a\|}\bigg)\right|}{\|h\|}  \le 
\frac{2 \|h\|}{\|a+h\| + \bigg(\|a\| + \frac{a\cdot h}{\|a\|}\bigg)}
$$
and the conclusion follows.

Comment: ooohh the trick was to recognize $\|a+h\|^{2} = (a+h) \cdot (a+h)$ and then proceed with the respective equivalent expressions

Comment: It should be $\|a+h\|^2$. That was the jist of my comment :-).

Comment: So I thought I had things worked out, but apparently not. Working with the simplification incorporating the denominator $\|h\|$, I have gotten: $\frac{\|h\|^2}{\|h\|}-\frac{(a \cdot h)^2}{\|h\|\|a\|^2} = \|h\| - \frac{(a \cdot h)^2}{\|h\|\|a\|^2} \leq \|h\| - \frac{(\|a\|\|h\|)^2}{\|h\|\|a\|^2} = \|h\| - \|h\| = 0$. Did I not apply the Cauchy Schwarz correctly?  EDIT: in my eagerness to prove things I forgot to incorporate the full denominator of the conjugation....I will leave this here for posterity

Comment: @dc3rd: I have added another step. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes. Beyond clear. Thanks.

Comment: For my own sanity: $\bigg | \|h\|^2-\frac{(a \cdot h)^2}{\|a\|^2} \bigg | \leq \bigg | \|h\|^2 + \frac{(a \cdot h)^2}{\|a\|^2} \bigg | \leq \|h\|^2 + \frac{|(a \cdot h|)^2}{\|a\|^2}$ (application of triangle inequality) and then finallly $\leq \|h\|^2 + \frac{(\|a\| \|h\|)^2}{\|a\|^2}$ by Cauchy Schwarz.....and then the rest as you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

Then we get

$\leq \frac{2\|h\|^2}{\|h\| (\|a+h\| + \|a\|+\frac{a\cdot h}{\|a\|}) } = \frac{2\|h\|}{\|a+h\| + \|a\|+\frac{a\cdot h}{\|a\|}} \to 0$ as $h \to 0$